# libnss-extrausers and user tasks

Tags: authentication, ubuntu, shadow, passwd, nameservice

I have Ubuntu 12.04. Installed libnss-extrausers and configured nsswitch.conf. Now, users registered in `/var/lib/extrausers/{passwd,group,shadow}` are recognized by the system and can login.

However, common user management programs (passwd, userdel, usermod, groupadd, groupmod) only work for users registered at `/etc/{passwd,group,shadow}`

Is there any configuration to make these programs work with libnss-extrausers, or simply recognize `/var/lib/extrausers/{passwd,group,shadow}` as user data files?

Comment: As a workaround I configured my machine as NIS server of itself, but I feel libnss-extrausers should be a much simpler way to have extra user files, in case anyone comes up with a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. It was a permission one. Try:

```
sudo chmod +r /var/lib/extrausers/*
```

Worked for me.

Cheers,

Comment: Isn't that a security issue? `/etc/shadow` has permission 640 instead of 644.

Comment: Also, it didn't work. Are you also using Ubuntu? Any extra configuration beyond editing those 3 lines in /etc/nsswitch.conf?

Comment: I agree. My suggested command is a little bit "dirty". The idea is to have the same permissions as for the corresponding group|passwd|shadow in /etc.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.1, libnss-extrausers=0.5-1

Comment: and I don't remember any other extra configuration beyond the nsswitch.conf

Comment: Mine is also libnss-extrausers 0.5-1 (Ubuntu 12.04.4). Changed permissions to 644. Still getting "Authentication token manipulation error" when trying to change password.